# Solutions for automation in constrained space

Tags: software-recommendation, automation

I've been asked to help automate a product overview catalog that looks something like this:

[image: Example]

Each gray line is one product, consisting of an item number, name and some information about packaging and 2-4 certificate images in the end. Each time there's some fluff it's a new category, like Tires (regular), Tires (wooden), Tires (concrete), etc. There can be any number of products in each category.

I'm looking for a good way to automate this task, hopefully while keeping it easy for my client to modify the basic template. I have everything ready, including the feed for the item information in any format I need. The primary challenge I'm faced with is trying to make sure it all fits nicely on a page, automatically, rather than just flowing everywhere. I'm constrained because it should fill as little as possible, as the end product should be a small A4 flyer with all products printed on both sides.

I have tried automating it with InDesign but I haven't been able to make something that grows automatically, in a relative fashion. I also tried making it as a webpage which worked decently, but didn't give me the print quality I needed. My current approach is to find a tool that is more suited for tasks like this, but I'm also open to any suggestions on how to solve it with the tools I've tried so far.

Comment: is this going to be printed? What's the final product?

Comment: Yes, this is for print. The final product is a 1-2 page flyer, printed on both sides for the sales team to bring to clients.

Comment: please [edit] your question to add this information

Comment: I believe Indesign is still the primary way to do something like this, but what does it mean "grow automatically in a relative fashion"?

Comment: Probably *not* cost effective, but [Adobe Framemaker](http://www.adobe.com/products/framemaker/features.html) is built on the notion of automated updates to complex documents via XML/DITA for output in both web and print formats.

Comment: You can instruct indesign to do nearly any dynamic behaviour via the scripting api.

Comment: @Silly-V, I mean that if I insert a few more lines between the fluff, it should position properly rather than having to reposition everything again. Similar to how HTML would behave.

Comment: @joojaa Yeah, it's very flexible, but I would like to still keep things flexible. Obviously I can just position all elements via the script, but then I have a system where the marketing department can't make changes without me updating the code.

Comment: @WilliamMariager then write a gui for the code, or ruleset. Anyway you might want to look at xml workflows with indesign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the images in a text box.  In other words, make each image an anchored graphic.

It's easiest to do when [the images and text are going in an actual grid](https://indesignsecrets.com/auto-reflowing-images-in-a-grid.php), but you should be able to do the format you describe as well.

Comment: I'll look into anchored graphics. It sounds like just what I need. Can I anchor other things as well, like a group?

Comment: @WilliamMariager, I *believe* so.  I don't have InDesign on this computer to check.  In my use of this approach, I grouped a frame and a caption and put them into the text box.  In other words, I didn't actually type anything into the text box—I just used it to handle the flow of the graphics I was putting in.  So yes.  :)

Comment: That sounds perfect. I'll give it a try as soon as possible.

Comment: This worked out nicely. Allowed me to easily insert the images. I ended up combining it with a table to get the desired effect.